# Can't get facebook getting access_token via GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, authorization, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I'm getting a status code of 404 when trying to get the access_token from facebook. The is a GAE app written in Java and I'm programmatically getting the access_token. That is, once I get the "code" I then make https request to get the access_token. I'm using the restlet.org framework.

```
public void getAccessToken( final Map<String,String> filter ) {
    //prepare and issue the request. Send in the host and other data
    String url = Application.getInstance().getAccessTokenUrl( this.getReference().getHostIdentifier(), filter );

    Client client = new Client(Protocol.HTTPS);
    client.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    Request request = new Request(Method.GET, url);

    client.handle(request, new Uniform() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Request arg0, Response response) {
            if ( response.getStatus().isSuccess() ) {
                if ( response.isEntityAvailable() ) {  
                    String result = response.getEntityAsText();
                    String results[] = result.split("&");
                    String accessTokens[] = results[0].split("=");
                    filter.put("access_token", accessTokens[1]);
                }
            } else {
                // the user doesn't exist
                log.warning("getAccessToken, description - " + response.getStatus().getDescription() + ", code - " + response.getStatus().getCode() + ", all - " + response.getStatus().toString());
                setStatus(new Status(Status.CLIENT_ERROR_NOT_FOUND, "Failed to get facebook access code."));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

where code, client_id, client_secret and redirectUrl all combine to create the correct http url.

This works perfectly well when I run it locally from my dev environment (192.168.1.../facebook/signin). However, when I run it on GAE, it returns a 404 when trying to retrieve the access_token. I've logged the http request that GAE is sending and it is correct. That is, if I plug the request ( https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=298631... ) into my browser, it correctly returns the access_token. I believe this confirms that the app settings are correct on Facebook.

So, it runs correctly when the code executes from my dev system,
it runs correctly when I plug in the URL that GAE is sending in my browser,
it only fails when GAE sends the http request.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what this might be or what to look for?

Comment: Where's the code? And the log entries?

Comment: OK, my bad... The redirect Url needed to be urlEncoded. Now it's working. Although, I'm still not sure why this worked from http://192.168.1... when the redirectUrl was not encoded either.

Comment: You should post details as an answer to your own question.